# Odoo can't add a new menuitem into menu

Tags: view, odoo, menuitem, odoo-9

I am trying to add a new menuitem into purchase menu the same like "Purchase" in the picture below:
[image]

My **openerp**.py:

```
"depends": [
    "purchase",
    "product",
    "base",
],
```

and **view**:

```
    <menuitem id="test" name="Test menu"
        parent="base.menu_purchase_root" sequence="2" />
```

Nothing happens, no errors and I can't see this menu item in **Purchases** menu.

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think without `action` or child menu, Odoo won't display your menu.

Comment: Simple and correct answer menu that do nothing are ignored by odoo

Answer (score 2):

You must add action to menu like define in purchase. For example:

```
 <menuitem
        action="product.product_category_action_form" id="menu_product_category_config_purchase"
        parent="purchase.menu_product_in_config_purchase" sequence="1" />
```

You can see this menu in front under **Purchase >> Configuration >> Product >> Product Category**

In this action is taken from product via its id. If you want to define your custom action then you can define it like this :

```
 <record id="product_normal_action_puchased" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">Products</field>
    <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
    <field name="res_model">product.template</field>
    <field name="view_type">form</field>
    <field name="view_mode">kanban,tree,form</field>
    <field name="context">{"search_default_filter_to_purchase":1}</field>
    <field name="search_view_id" eval="False"/> <!-- Force empty -->
    <field name="view_id" eval="False"/> <!-- Force empty -->
    <field name="help" type="html">
      <p class="oe_view_nocontent_create">
        Click to define a new product.
      </p><p>
        You must define a product for everything you purchase, whether
        it's a physical product, a consumable or services you buy to
        subcontractors.
      </p><p>
        The product form contains detailed information to improve the
        purchase process: prices, procurement logistics, accounting data,
        available vendors, etc.
      </p>
    </field>
</record>
```

And now after defining custom action give it's id to your menu like this :

```
      <!-- Product menu-->
  <menuitem name="Products" id="menu_procurement_partner_contact_form" action="product_normal_action_puchased"
      parent="menu_procurement_management" sequence="20"/>
```

By this way you can able to add menu and after that while defining action you need to add your view under **view_id** This helps to open a view after clicking on particular menu.